# Graph theory - finding a fixed-length path that maximizes weight

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, fsm

Let there be a finite, directed, edge-weighted graph.

Given a start point and an exact length, I'd like to get a path that maximizes total sum of edge weights. The path does not need to be simple i.e. it can visit a vertex multiple times.

Or equivalently, given a "weighted FSM" and a fixed length *N*, get an input string whose length is *N* that maximizes utility.

Is it possible to be translated into a well-known graph problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well, how about to use Dijkstra's algorithm, only not to minimize the sums, but to maximize them?

Comment: @Belphegor, I think Dijkstra's algorithm has several issues to apply to this problem as it returns a path which is simple and has variable length. Also, the maximization version seems to be not feasible as the following link suggests: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17980/is-it-possible-to-modify-dijkstra-algorithm-in-order-to-get-the-longest-path
I'm pretty sure that this is not a NP-hard problem though since the path length is fixed. It should be bound to `O(|V|^L)` time (`L` = path length) even for the brute-force one, but I'd like to know if much better algorithm exists.